# ContextMenuStrip and mouse wheel

Tags: c#, winforms, mousewheel, contextmenustrip

I have a ContextMenuStrip with many items.

How to handle mouse wheel to scroll throught items?

I search the net but nothing find usefull.

Or how to get first/last displayed/visible item from contextmenu?

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a old question you probably wont need this, but just in-case and for future reference.
You can **simulate** key up and down presses to scroll through it, its **far from perfect** but it beats having to write your own *ContextMenuStrip* to handle the scroll wheel.
[Mouse wheel scrolling Toolstrip menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139074/mouse-wheel-scrolling-toolstrip-menu-items/13145558#13145558)

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is very old, someone may still benefit from my input...

```
var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
menu.MouseWheel += (ob, ev) => SendKeys.SendWait(ev.Delta > 0 ? "{UP}" : "{DOWN}");
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding so many items to a CMS that it requires to be scrolled completely defeats the purpose of a context menu.  Don't design a UI that's hard to use and requires the user to scan through dozens of items.  Your users will dislike you program with a passion and will find out where you live.

A CMS supports sub-menus.  Categorize your menu items.

Comment: Believe me, I already know all those stuffs you write about but it doesn't matter for me for my purpose.